# Why Java Method Reference of instance method cannot be assigned to Consumer interface

Tags: java, lambda

Here is my Code :

```
public class SearchByLambda {

     private Map<String,Consumer<Person>> searchCritertiaHolder = new HashMap<String,Consumer<Person>>();

     private static final String AGED = "aged";

     public SearchByLambda(){
           searchCritertiaHolder.put(AGED, (Person p)-> {p.filterAgedPerson(p);} );
     }

     private Consumer<Person> getFilter(String personType){
          return searchCritertiaHolder.get(personType);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          SearchByLambda searchUsage = new SearchByLambda();
          Person p = new Person(59,"shailesh");
          Person p1 = new Person(58,"ganesh");

          searchUsage.getFilter(AGED).accept(p);
          searchUsage.getFilter(AGED).accept(p1);

          Person.printAgedPersons();
     }
 }

 class Person{

       private static List<Person> agedPersons = new ArrayList<>();

       private int age;

       private String name;

       public int getAge() {
              return age;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
          this.age = age;
       }

       public String getName() {
            return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
       }

       public Person(int age,String name){
           this.age = age;
           this.name = name;
       }

       public void filterAgedPerson(Person person){
          if(person.getAge() > 58){
              agedPersons.add(person);
          }
       }

       public static void printAgedPersons(){
            for(Person person : agedPersons){
                System.out.println(person.getName());
            }
       }
 }
```

When I replace following Lambda expression

```
     searchCritertiaHolder.put(AGED, (Person p)-> {p.filterAgedPerson(p);});
```

with

```
              searchCritertiaHolder.put(AGED, Person::filterAgedPerson);
```

it gives me compilation error. I am using java 8 and and compiling through eclipse. Why is this so? Why cannot I assign method reference for instance method of any arbitrary object to consumer functional interface?

Comment: have tried with `::`, `Person::filterAgedPerson`?

Comment: Sorry its a typo. I tried with Person::filterAgedPerson only. Edited the post. Thanks for bringing to my notice

Comment: Well, I tested your code and it's fine. All I had to do was made `filterAgedPerson` static.

Comment: Ok. But I would like to rather pass method reference to instance method of Person class through shortcut notation and not method reference to static method. Any ideas?. Java tutorial on oracle clearly says its possible to pass method reference and can be assigned to functional interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition of `filterAgedPerson` takes a `Person` as an argument, even though it is not a static method.  It doesn't need to, and it shouldn't if you want to use it as a `Consumer<Person>`.  What you are ending up with is something compatible with `BiConsumer<Person, Person>`.

It might help to think of it this way: method references to non-static methods always take an "extra" argument which is used as `this`.

The easiest way for you to fix this with your current code structure is to modify the `filterAgedPerson` method to not take a `Person` as an argument

```
   public void filterAgedPerson() {
      if (this.getAge() > 58) {
          agedPersons.add(person);
      }
   }
```

As an aside, you might want to also consider making your filters `Predicate<Person>` instead of `Consumer<Person>` and moving the results handling elsewhere. This will give you more flexibility as things get more complicated.

Comment: Yes this is very helpful. So you mean to say I can only use Shortcut notation for instance methods if it either doesn't accept any argument or use BiConsumer than Consumer. Correct? I was just playing with the lambda and ofcourse from design perspective the code is not ideal but thanks. I will accept the answer once I try your solutions.

Comment: I guess making the instance method not accept any comment is the best solution.  But  then does it mean I cannot represent instance methods which take any arguments by shortcut notations? Or I can but the type of the argument should be different from this?

Comment: No it doesn't work if I try with any other type of argument. Why?

Comment: In this case, it would be cleaner to keep the `Person` parameter and turn the method into a `static` method as it’s modifying a static property of the `Person` class. But, as already said in this answer, separating predicate and action would be even cleaner…